How to tell mathematica that the objects are arbitrary symbolic matrices of unspecified dimensions (and not numbers)
Consider the code:
FullSimplify[A (B + F) + B (A + F)]

It returns:
 2 A B + (A + B) F

This is because Mathematica by default assumes A, B, F are numbers (and not matrices). If they were matrices AB+BA would not be equal to 2AB for instance.
How can I tell mathematica to simplify it while treating all the elements inside as arbitrary matrices. I don't want to specify any dimension for the matrices, I want it to work as if they were symbolic matrices.
I am using mathematica 14.0.

There is support added for symbolic matrices in V 14.1. see yet-more-new-ideas-and-new-functions-launching-version-14-1-of-wolfram-language-mathematica  search for Symbolic Arrays and Their Calculus ALso in help. But need V  14.1

Alternatively, if you only need a non-commutative multiplication, there is NonCommutativeMultiply, and many many questions about using it on this SE :)
